# How to Fetch a single Object Details using its ObjectID in a CA Agile Central (AKA Rally) Custom App?

Tags: rally

I have an app which is fetching data from Lookback API. I get User ObjectID in the data, however I would like to get the DisplayName of the User instead of ObjectID. Rally Lookback API does not allow to Hydrate User field, so I cannot have User Name while loading Lookback API Data. 
I tried creating store with user Object ID filter to get the User Name, but I don't get the name of the user, until Lookback API data load is complete. By the time Lookback API data load is complete my data operations are also complete. So loading User Name after first load is not useful. I tried setting async property of Store to false/true, didn't work.
Any way to accomplish this with Rally SDK 2.0?
Here is the Code Block -

```
//Lookback call
_getStoriesByUser: function (user_story_ids, user_oids, user_story_state, users) {
    this.acceptedByTM = [];
    var scheduleStates = [];
    scheduleStates.push('Accepted');
    scheduleStates.push('Released to Prod');

    var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
    var me = this;
    console.time("FetchingLBData");
    var snapshotStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        "context": this.getContext().getDataContext(),
        "fetch": ["ScheduleState", "_User", "_PreviousValues.ScheduleState"],
        "hydrate": ["ScheduleState"],
        "find": {
            "ObjectID": { "$in": user_story_ids },
            //"_User": { "$in": user_oids },
            "_TypeHierarchy": "HierarchicalRequirement",
            "ScheduleState": { "$in": scheduleStates },
            "_PreviousValues.ScheduleState": { "$ne": null },
            "Children": null
        },
        "sort": { "_ValidFrom": -1 }
    });

    snapshotStore.load({
        callback: function (records, operation) {
            if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                console.timeEnd("FetchingLBData");
                me.logger.log("LB US Count >>", records.length, records)
                var total_us_accepted_by_tm = 0;
                var tmAcceptedUS = 0;
                var nontmAcceptedUS = 0;
                var tm_accepted = [];
                Ext.Array.each(user_story_state, function (uss) {
                    Ext.Array.each(records, function (rec) {
                        if ((rec.get('ObjectID') == uss.ObjectID && rec.get('ScheduleState') == 'Accepted') && (uss.ScheduleState == 'Accepted' || uss.ScheduleState == 'Released to Prod')) {
                            total_us_accepted_by_tm += 1;
                            tm_accepted.push({ ObjectID: rec.get('ObjectID'), UserObjectID: rec.get('_User') });
                                var userName;
                                //userName = me._fetchUserName(rec.get('_User')).value;
                                me._fetchUserName(rec.get('_User')).then({
                                    success: function (records) {
                                        userName = records[0].get('DisplayName')
                                    },
                                    failure: function (error) {
                                        console.log('Error in Execution:', error)
                                    }
                                }).always(function() {
                                    console.log('Waiting for Update!');
                                });
                                //userName = rec.get('_User').DisplayName;
                                console.log('Accepted By Name: ', userName);

                                me.acceptedByTM.push({ ObjectID: rec.get('ObjectID'), UserObjectID: userName });
                                return false;

                        }
                    });

                });

                deferred.resolve(me.acceptedByTM);
            } else {
                deferred.reject('Problem querying lookback');
            }
        },
        scope: me
    });
    return deferred;
},

//Get User Details for a given user
_fetchUserName: function (userObjId) {
    var me = this;
    var userName;
    var userDetails;
    var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
    me.logger.log("Fetching User Information for User >>", userObjId);

    var userFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
        property: 'ObjectID',
        value: userObjId
    });

    userDetails = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        fetch: ['ObjectID', 'DisplayName'],
        filters: userFilter,
        limit: 1,
        pageSize: 1
    });

    userDetails.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
            console.log("Operation Status: ", operation.synchronous);
            if (success) {
                //userName = records[0].get('DisplayName');
                deferred.resolve(records);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(Ext.String.format("Error getting {0} count for {1}: {2}", 'User', userFilter.toString(), operation.error.errors.join(',')));
            }
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?  It shouldn't be too hard to do this.  Once your lookback store is loaded you just need to loop through the data and load the users from wsapi.  It sounds like you have a lot of that already, and maybe just need some help managing all the async code?

Comment: Hello Kyle, I have included the code in original post.

Comment: @KyleMorse, Did you find any solution? I tried loading the Active Users and Disabled Users into local variable, by including Deft.Promise.All at the load of the application. But Users get loaded after completion of the Lookback Data load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to simplify things I'd probably just load all the users up front from WSAPI and build a map of them by objectid.  That way you already have all the data and can just directly do the lookup when you're processing your lookback snapshots.

Something like this:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function () {
        this._loadUsersFromWsapi().then({
            success: function (users) { 
                this.usersByOid = _.indexBy(users, function(user) {
                    return user.getId();
                });
                this._loadSnapshotData();
            },
            scope: this
        });
    },

    _loadUsersFromWsapi: function () {
        return Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'user',
            limit: Infinity,
            pageSize: 2000,
            fetch: ['ObjectID']
        }).load();
    },

    _loadSnapshotData: function () { 
        //Now in here for any given snapshot you can get the user
        //information by looking it up in the this.usersByOid map
        var userName = this._usersByOid[userObjectID].get('_refObjectName');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you So much Kyle. It worked like a charm. However, it has impacted the performance of the app as we are fetching all users data, which is what I needed. Is there any other way to get user name with Lookback? I know we cannot hydrate User field, but having something where we can just fetch required User Name by its Object ID would keep optimum performance of the App.

Comment: There's no way to get it via lookback.  What you could do is make the lookback and user requests in parallel using Deft.Promise.all, and then stitch the data back together in that success handler rather than making the requests serially like my code above does ^^